# Python ijson parse file (ijson from softwaremaniacs.org )

Tags: python, json, unix

I need a little help to parse a large JSON file.
Here I have just a sample of the data (only 2 items).

I need to use the parse method. `open()` does not work, because the file is too large.

```
parser=ijson.parse("sample.json")
```

I need to loop and print out the `Identifier` from all the `Assets`.

It cannot be so hard, but I cannot get the correct code.

Thank you for any helpful tips.

Peter

json data:

```
{
  "AssetCount": 2,
  "Server": "xy",
  "Assets": [
    {
      "Identifier": "21979c09fc4e6574"
    },
    {
      "Identifier": "e6235cce58ec8b9c"
    }
 ]
}
```

Answer (score 8):

Try `ijson.parse(open('sample.json'))`. The output will look something like

```
list(ijson.parse(open('sample.json')))

[('', u'start_map', None),
 ('', u'map_key', u'Server'),
 (u'Server', u'string', u'xy'),
 ('', u'map_key', u'Assets'),
 (u'Assets', u'start_array', None),
 (u'Assets.item', u'start_map', None),
 (u'Assets.item', u'map_key', u'Identifier'),
 (u'Assets.item.Identifier', u'string', u'21979c09fc4e6574'),
 (u'Assets.item', u'end_map', None),
 (u'Assets.item', u'start_map', None),
 (u'Assets.item', u'map_key', u'Identifier'),
 (u'Assets.item.Identifier', u'string', u'e6235cce58ec8b9c'),
 (u'Assets.item', u'end_map', None),
 (u'Assets', u'end_array', None),
 ('', u'map_key', u'AssetCount'),
 (u'AssetCount', u'number', 2),
 ('', u'end_map', None)]
```

ijson is also available from pypi.

Comment: I don't know why I didn't think of this way to investigate into ijson. Thanks, it really helped

Answer (score 7):

This is probably too late, but anyway…

`ijson.parse` is a lower level function, you want `ijson.items` instead which does all the prefix filtering and object construction for you:

```
import ijson
f = open('sample.json', 'rb')
for id in ijson.items(f, 'Assets.item.Identifier'):
    # do something with id
```

Note: ijson wants your file in binary form, hence the 'rb' mode in `open`.

Comment: Is there any documentation to explain the details of the API? and how it works?

Answer (score 3):

better to try like

```
import ijson

file_name="sample.json"

with open(file_name) as file:

    parser = ijson.parse(file)

    for prefix, event, value in parser:

        if prefix=="AssetCount":

            print value

        if prefix=="Server":

            print value

        if prefix=="Assets.item.Identifier":

            print value
```

ouput like:

```
2

xy

21979c09fc4e6574

e6235cce58ec8b9c
```